# 'plotAtlas' function in Morpho package

Tags: plot, computational-geometry, surface, mathematical-morphology, facial-landmark-alignment

I am trying to plot my mesh with its respective landmarks and semi-landmarks. I provided all matrices but when I plotted the mesh it appeared completely empty. For some reason my LMs and semi-landmarks didn`t show up. Someone would have any idea if this might be some kind of incompatibility of my LMs matrices?

Thanks in advance

I expected my LMs and semi-landmarks would appear over my mesh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.